# media queries look good in dreamweaver, but don't fill the page

Tags: css, media-queries

I created a one page layout in Dreamweaver cc 2015 and I keep running into issues with the mobile media query. It only fills 75% of the page.

I have this in my head, `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">` and my media query for mobile phones is

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 499px) {a bunch of CSS}
```

I have the site up in a hidden folder: http://www.carefreebuildings.com/gerardco/home.html

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about that the margin on the left side of the page -- your problem is you have 2% margin added to a few of your section ids, if you remove that 'margin-left: 2%' your sections will move over and cover the whole page. if you can provide more details we can better assist. Let me know if this helps and if you want to provide more CSS, that would be great.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I took out the margin-left comment on all the media queries. It still doesn't fill the screen. The desktop version works great. It bugs me that the header is fixed and filled the page, but the rest of the site doesn't follow along. And the mobile layout looks good in dreamweaver, just not on the phone.

Comment: I can't post all the css, but here is a link: http://www.carefreebuildings.com/gerardco/style.css Thanks again for helping me.

Comment: I took out an Xpose Gallery from ExtendStudio and the site worked in mobile. I sent them a support request in hope that they can help. The gallery works great on the other devices, just not on mobile.

Comment: Hopefully they can help! Sorry I wasn't more help. If you can post all the code I could definitely be of more assistants!